# Intellij does not find wrong xhtml attribute

Tags: intellij-idea, primefaces, attributes, xhtml

Intellij IDEA 2023.1.3 (Ultimate)

Hi,

I updated from Primefaces 7 to 8 and there was this change: FileUpload#fileUploadListener has been renamed into listener.

I did not change this and the error was found later. Now I wanted to find Intellij such types of errors and tried "Inspect Code", but as result no wrong attribute was found.
I can name the attribute whatever I want, it is not marked as wrong. In the settings I tried to activate everything which nearly has to do something with this, no effect.

How can I find stuff like this with Intellij tools?

Comment: Please report issue on YouTrack (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) providing file example.

Comment: Also just to add this was in the migration guide from 7.0 to 8.0 as well: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/12_0_0/#/../migrationguide/8_0

Comment: @Melloware Yes, I overlooked it. But as the error occured the migration guide helped me out to figure out whats happening.